# How can I put CSS style in my I18n locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I have a following translation:

`welcome: Hello there, %{general_kenobi}`

Now I know, that I can put HTML tags in the translation, like `<em>` or so. But what if I want this `general_kenobi` to have my custom style? How do I implement it? I've tried to google it, but didn't find anythin useful (or maybe I'm just bad at googling). Thank in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add something fancy like this to your locale you must add the `_html` extension to the key.

[From the docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-safe-html-translations)

> Keys with a '_html' suffix and keys named 'html' are marked as HTML
> safe. When you use them in views the HTML will not be escaped.

```yaml
en:
  welcome_html: "<b>Bolded text</b>"
```

then just the regular stuff in your views

```
<%= t('welcome_html')
```